# Subview / Loading indicator not visible

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uiview, subview

**Mission: Generic Loader**

Created a generic `LoadingViewController` to handle loading and display a loading indicator from any UIView (see photo).

[image]

**Issue: Not always displayed**

The indicator is not displayed if the user clicks the refresh button (top left) which immediately downloads relevant data and should display the loading indicator in the meantime.

However if the user clicks the filter icon (top right) and presented another UIView (push) and selects a few options and is delegated back to the mapView the loader indicator displays as expected - during loading data and is then removed.

The frame for the subView holding the loadingIndicator seems fine (0,0, 375, 667) in both instances. What could be at play?

**Refresh Button**

```
@IBAction func refreshPlaces(sender: AnyObject) {
    downloadStores = true
    updateStores()
}
```

**Delegate Function from Filter**

```
func filterViewDidFinish(controller: BudgetTableViewController, download: Bool) {

    // Dismiss modal
    self.navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true) // Pop back to map

    // Update stores
    downloadStores = download
    updateStores()

}
```

**Update Stores**

```
func updateStores(){

    // Display loading indicator
    println("Display loading indicator")
    let subViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoadingViewController") as! LoadingViewController
    let loadingSubView: UIView = subViewController.view
    loadingSubView.tag = 1 // Unique identifier

    // Add loading indicator
    self.navigationController!.view.addSubview(loadingSubView)

    // Verify frame is OK
    println("Frame: \(self.navigationController!.view.viewWithTag(1)?.frame)")

    // Async
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        // Update location
        subViewController.status.text = "Updating your location"
        self.getCoordinates()

        // Get stores
        if self.downloadStores == true {
            subViewController.status.text = "Finding stores nearby"
            self.getStores()
        }

        // Create markers
        self.googleMapsMarkers()

        // Dismiss loading indicator
        println("Remove loading indicator")
        self.navigationController!.view.viewWithTag(1)?.removeFromSuperview()

    })
}
```

**UPDATE**

The Loading Indicator gets displayed also on the 'refresh button' if I remove the `self.navigationController!.view.viewWithTag(1)?.removeFromSuperview()`.

**Question is WHY is it being removed before the data is downloaded** (i.e. the functions higher in the Async que are finished)?

I understood the async que as that things operate in the background until they are done, and that a function entered into the que should only be executed when a previous function in the que is done - but perhaps I am mistaken?

New to swift... :)

Comment: the object isn't getting destroyed and recreated is it?

Comment: @Woodstock: Not that I am aware of. It gets created but then 'immediately' removed. The Loading Indicator gets displayed also on the 'refresh button' if I remove the `self.navigationController!.view.viewWithTag(1)?.removeFromSuperview()`. So the question is WHY is it being removed before the data is downloaded (i.e. the functions higher in the Async que are finished)?

I understood the async que as that things operate in the background until they are done, and that a function entered into the que should only be executed when a previous function in the que is done - but perhaps I am mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be adding views directly into your navigation controller's view. If you want to present a child view controller that overlays over your current view you should do it correctly by calling the right api methods:

```
subViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:subViewController.view];
[self addChildViewController:subViewController];
[subViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: I get the same behavior even if I add the subview directly to the existing view `self.view.addSubview(loadingSubView)`. I.e. it works for the "filter button" (via another UIView) but not on the "refresh button".

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this](https://github.com/Rannie/Toast-Swift) might be helpful for you. Have a look at UIView extension where activity indicator is added to view

Comment: Can you guys please tell me the reasons of down voting ? Check the UIView extension on that library for generic loading indicator

Comment: My guess is because you didn't provide an answer to the question but rather a link (with no context) to an alternate/similar tool. This seems like it would be better as a comment, as it doesn't actually ***answer*** the question.